# Getting value of Javascript prompt

Tags: javascript, prompt

I'm using C# and I have an aspx page that when the button is clicked a javascript prompt appears that allows the user to enter a mandatory comment. I used the onClientClick property for the button like so:

OnClientClick = "return prompt('Enter a comment for rejecting the action:');"

However I would like to capture the comment that was entered by the user and then store it in a string variable that will eventually be written to the database. But my main problem is getting the value that was entered in the prompt by the user for my string variable...Any help would be appreciated....

Answer (score 0):

If i understood it correctly you are looking for:

```
OnClientClick = "return x=prompt('Enter a comment for rejecting the action:');"
```

than you have value in x variable